# receive error "getTokens does not support retrieving tokens while signed" when try to retrieve data from AWS via API Gateway

Tags: aws-amplify

issue:
console show "getTokens does not support retrieving tokens while signed-" error.
    step:
    1. run app with Android studio
    2. log in AWS ( my app use amplify drop-in UI )
    3. retrieve data from AWS via API Gateway  --> result OK ( able to retrieve)
    4. log out and log in again
    5. retrieve data from AWS via API Gateway --> result NG ( show above error)

```
note:
my configuration file include: Cognito User pool and Identity pool. this is auto generate after keyin " amplify add auth" at CLI.
if i deleted  Cognito Identity pool from configuration file, issue not happen.
May i know why ?


my configuration file:
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },

    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "xxx",
                "Region": "us-east-2"
            }
        }
    },

    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "us-east-2_xxx",
            "AppClientId": "xxx",
            "AppClientSecret": "xxx",
            "Region": "us-east-2"
        }
    }
}

sign-in code:
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(getApplicationContext(), new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {

                switch (userStateDetails.getUserState()) {
                    case SIGNED_IN:

                                Intent i = new Intent(Authentication.this, AvailableFlavor.class);

                        break;

                    case SIGNED_OUT:
                       showSignIn();

                        break;


                    default:
                        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signOut();
                        showSignIn();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {

            }
        });
    }


    private void showSignIn() {
        try {
            AWSMobileClient.getInstance().showSignIn(this,
                    SignInUIOptions.builder().nextActivity(LoginSuccess.class)
                                                        .build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //  Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the end of the error is "getTokens does not support retrieving tokens while signed-"...out?
I had a similar error, please check if your identity poolId is correct (even if you're not using a guest access or if you only want to use the user pool functionality) in app -> src -> res -> raw -> `amplifyconfiguration.json` & `awsconfiguration.json`. You can find your poolId in your AWS console -> cognito -> manage identity pools -> click on your pool -> click on Sample code.:

[image]